# Can't bring public arrayList to another class

Tags: java, arraylist

In my main class, which is initialized as "theGame", I have this code

```
public ArrayList<Augment> augments =new ArrayList<Augment>();
```

Augment is a class with objects initialized as it and without errors

And in another class, I have this code

```
private ArrayList<Augment> installedAugments(){
    ArrayList<Augment> IA= new ArrayList <Augment>();
    for (Augment a:theGame.augments){
        if (a.installed==true){
            IA.add(a);
        }
    }
    return IA;
}
```

However when I reference "theGame" Eclipse tells me "theGame" cannot be resolved to a variable. Does anyone know the possible causes and solutions for this problem?

Edit: Well, it was called theGame in public static void main, but the question turned out to be an issue of parameters because it turned out that it can't access a predefined object I guess.

Comment: Have you declared the variable `theGame` in another class?

Comment: I think he means that `theGame` is the name of the other class.

Comment: What do you mean by ' ... main class, which is initialized as "theGame" ... ' ? Can you show the code that does this step, just to clarify your meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because scoping. The method `installedAugments()` doesn't know about the existance of `theGame`, so it can't use that variable.

**What can you do?** You can pass `theGame` as a parameter to `installedAugments()`, so it can use that reference:

```
private ArrayList<Augment> installedAugments(MainClassName pTheGame){
   // ...
   for (Augment a : pTheGame.augments)
   // ...
}
```

You have to replace `MainClassName` with the name of your class name (the type of `theGame`).

Answer (score 0):

If `theGame` is the name of the class, then in order to reference `augments`, you would need to declare `augments` as a static field within `theGame` class